# what is the kubectl equivalent of ibmcloud ks cluster get --cluster CLUSTER_NAME?

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, terraform, ibm-cloud, kubectl

I am trying to deploy the jpetstore application (https://github.com/IBM-Cloud/jpetstore-kubernetes) into kubernetes in EKS and i am having trouble interpreting this command as it is used for IBM cloud:

```
ibmcloud ks cluster get --cluster CLUSTER_NAME
```

What is the EKS equivalent if i were to use `kubectl` ?

I have EKS setup using the terraform below:

```
provider "kubernetes" {
  host                   = data.aws_eks_cluster.cluster.endpoint
  cluster_ca_certificate = base64decode(data.aws_eks_cluster.cluster.certificate_authority.0.data)
  token                  = data.aws_eks_cluster_auth.cluster.token
}
```

could command be retrieving the endpoint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Cluster Name:**

```
$ kubectl config get-clusters
NAME
kubernetes
```

**Cluster end point info:**

```
$ kubectl cluster-info
Kubernetes master is running at https://172.17.0.109:6443
dash-kubernetes-dashboard is running at https://172.17.0.109:6443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/https:dash-kubernetes-dashboard:https/proxy
KubeDNS is running at https://172.17.0.109:6443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/kube-dns:dns/proxy

To further debug and diagnose cluster problems, use 'kubectl cluster-info dump'.
```